# What do you call a water tap placed on the outside of a house?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, technical, image-identification

What do you call a water tap placed on the outside of a house?

[image: Picture of external tap]

I'm looking for the correct technical term in English. Here in Sweden there seems to be only one vendor and model, which I'm not so fond of, so with the right technical term I can search the internet for alternatives.

Comment: Outdoor/Outside/External/Garden tap are all used. _Standpipe_ is sometimes used but on looking at a few dictionary definitions it must have a colloquial meaning of _public water supply via a pipe topped with a tap_ that hasn't found it's way into any dictionaries. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standpipe_(street) which at least confirms some of my understanding of _standpipe_

Comment: You have ***hot*** water running to the outside??  Wow!

Comment: The answers below answer your question, but, as a Canadian I am jealous of the tap you find inadequate. They're better than anything I've seen available here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is called  [outside  tap](http://www.diydoctor.org.uk/projects/installing_an_outside_tap.htm) or garden tap:

> - Fitting an [Outside](http://www.diydoctor.org.uk/projects/installing_an_outside_tap.htm) Tap - How to Install a Garden Tap Yourself

Comment: I also found *garden tap* when looking for *outside tap*. There's also *external tap*. [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=outside+tap+kit), which produces decent results for me.

Answer (score 4):

Also note the term *[sillcock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sillcock)* (wiktionary: “A faucet designed to be installed horizontally on the outside wall of a building, typically to attach a hose”).  Closely related terms include  “Water spigot ... valve, hose hydrant, hose bibb, or sillcock” as noted in a caption in the [valve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sillcock) wikipedia article.

Comment: Yeah, *sillcock* is the term I hear the most often in the US, and is the term that plumbers generally use.  (Though truth be told, most people don't know what to call it, so terms such as "outside faucet" are often heard.)

Answer (score 0):

In the US it's called a *bibb* or *[bibcock](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bibcock)* [*American Heritage*]

Comment: Google *sillcock* and *bibcock*.  See which one comes up with the most images of the item.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK they are known as Bib Taps or Bib Cocks.  If they have a hose attachment they are known as Hose Union Bib Taps/Cocks.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Comment: Never hear this usage in the UK...

Answer (score -2):

in australia they are just called "garden tap"